# Android: AIDL refusing to generate code from aidl file defining parcelable

Tags: android, aidl

I am trying to build a library with aidls.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java) \
java/com/testapp/Istudent.aidl \
java/com/testapp/Itest.aidl \

LOCAL_PREBUILT_JAVA_LIBRARY := framework.jar
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

I am trying to refer the Istudent in Itest.

Istudent.aidl

```
package com.testapp;

parcelable Istudent;
```

Istudent.java

```
public class Istudent implements Parcelable{}
```

Itest.aidl

```
package com.testapp;

import  com.testapp.Istudent;

interface IAP2InterfaceBase {}
```

**But error I receive is  E 07-11 20:05:37 71066 71066 aidl.cpp:580] refusing to generate code from aidl file defining parcelable**

Kindly let me know what we mean by "refusing to generate code from aidl file defining parcelable" ? And what wrong I am doing here..

Answer (score 4):

**Reason for Error can be understood as per below source code of aidl:**

https://github.com/debian-pkg-android-tools/android-platform-system-tools-aidl/blob/master/aidl.cpp Line:536

```
if (!interface) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "refusing to generate code from aidl file defining "
                  "parcelable";
    return AidlError::FOUND_PARCELABLE;
  }
```

Also the aidl file that declares your parcelable class is not supposed to be included in build as mentioned on https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html under 'Passing Objects over IPC'. Below snippet copied from the website.

> Finally, create an .aidl file that declares your parcelable class (as
>   shown for the Rect.aidl file, below). If you are using a custom build
>   process, do not add the .aidl file to your build. Similar to a header
>   file in the C language, this .aidl file isn't compiled.

Comment: Follow up question: my build process is not custom but I still get these errors, they are benign but I would still like to clean them up. How can I exclude my parcelables from compilation in my build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you have resolved this issue. I encountered the same problem, resolved it by downgrade Android SDK build tool to an earlier version, the build tool versions below 24 should be working, I used version 23.0.3

Comment: That is not really an answer to the question. And Downgrading tools is rarely good advise - sooner or later that version is gone, and then what?

Answer (score -1):

In your android.mk file replace

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java) \
    java/com/testapp/Istudent.aidl \
    java/com/testapp/Itest.aidl \
```

with-----------

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java) $(call all-Iaidl-files-under, java)
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := $(call all-Iaidl-files-under, java)
```

Comment: If you see aidl.cpp file, you couldn't include in your make file, simply answer written by @optimus .

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue with you. The $(call all-java-files-under, java) command will find all aidl files whose name start with "I" (I*.aidl), but the parcelable class should not be included. Two solutions:

(1) Change the parcelable class name, do not start with "I":

```
parcelable Student;
```

(2) Move Istudent.aidl from LOCAL_SRC_FILES to LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java) \
    java/com/testapp/Itest.aidl

LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := java/com/testapp/Istudent.aidl
```